# Calling function and passing arguments multiple times

Tags: python, function, loops

I want to call the function multiple time and use it's returned argument everytime when it's called. For example:

```
  def myfunction(first, second, third):
         return (first+1,second+1,third+1)
```

1st call: `myfunction(1,2,3)`
2nd call is going to be pass returned variables: `myfunction(2,3,4)` and loop it until defined times. How can I do such loop? Thank you!

Comment: `for i in range(n):
 print myfunction(i,i+1,i+2)`

Comment: @Ajay it works great in the given example. But when it comes to pass string it won't. Thanks for the comment btw :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a,b,c = 1,2,3
while i<n:
    a,b,c = myfunction(a,b,c)
    i +=1
```

Comment: Note `v = (1,2,3)` and `v = myfunction(*v)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def myF(x,y,z,i):
    print x, i
    while i:
        x += 1
        i -= 1
        return myF(x,i)
```

This will keep calling `myF` until `i` is `0` which will break the `while` loop, example:

```
>>> myF(1,10)
1 10
2 9
3 8
4 7
5 6
6 5
7 4
8 3
9 2
10 1
11 0
```

For three arguments, you can do as follows:

```
>>> def myF(x,y,z,i):
        print x,y,z,i
        while i:
            i -= 1
            x,y,z = map(lambda s:s+1,(x,y,z))
            return myF(x,y,z,i)


>>> 
>>> 
>>> myF(1,1,1,10)
1 1 1 10
2 2 2 9
3 3 3 8
4 4 4 7
5 5 5 6
6 6 6 5
7 7 7 4
8 8 8 3
9 9 9 2
10 10 10 1
11 11 11 0
```

Comment: `return` in the loop breaks the loop on the first iteration.

Comment: Then why use the `while i` loop at all? And what's up with the inconsistent `y` and `z` arguments?

Comment: Obviously the `while` loop is keep calling `myF` function `i` times...and what is it with the `x` and `z`???...why you said **inconsistent** ?